# Create array of counters in Javascript (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

Before i start i just want to mention that i already have a code that create array of counters using reduce but sometimes i get an error with that and i wonder if there is another way

**This is a query that gets me an array of objects:**

```
const handleService = (bUID) => {
  const serviceListTmp = [];
  const  serviceCode = [];
  firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).collection("my-appointments").where("businessId", "==", bUID).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      serviceListTmp.push(doc.data());
    })
    setServiceObj(serviceListTmp);
    console.log("Service Obj ", serviceObj);
  })
}
```

**Data for example:**

```
 Array [
    Object {
        "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
        "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
        "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
        "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
        "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
      }
// more data
]
```

**What i want to do is this:**

1. I want to count how many times a **"serviceType"** appeared in the data
2. After that i want to check which **"serviceType"** is appear maximum times and minimum times
3. Then, i want to add the **"voucherCode"** to the matching **"serviceType"**

**Exmaple of wanted outcome:**

```
"Learn JavaScript" : "2"(counter) //Maximum used
"do something" : "1"(counter) //Minimum used
```

Now, i want to add to the maximum used service is matching voucherCode from the example Data

I tried to make something simple but i made it complicated as hell, is their any way to make this much simpler?

Comment: your data is array?

Comment: Array of objects

Comment: What do you mean by add  "voucherCode" to the matching "serviceType" ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan i have added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reduce function to group data and then order data and then get first and last item of that array to get min and max

```js
const array1 = [{
    "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
    "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
    "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
    "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
    "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
  },
  {
    "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
    "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
    "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
    "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
    "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
  },
  {
    "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
    "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
    "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
    "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript2",
    "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
  },
  {
    "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
    "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
    "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
    "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript3",
    "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu11",
  },
  {
    "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
    "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
    "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
    "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript3",
    "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu11",
  },
  {
    "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
    "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
    "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
    "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript3",
    "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu11",
  }
];
const reducer = (a, c) => {
  const item = a.find(x => x.serviceType == c.serviceType);
  if (item) {
    item.count++;
  } else {
    a.push({
      serviceType: c.serviceType,
      count: 1,
      voucherCode: c.voucherCode
    })
  }
  return a;
};
// Reduce the array and get a grouped output of serviceType and count
const data = array1.reduce(reducer, []);
// Sort the array based on count
data.sort((x, y) => x.count > y.count);

//Generate an object using first and last element of array which is
// highest and lowest count as the array is sorted
console.log({
  [data[0].serviceType]: {
    count: data[0].count,
    voucherCode: data[0].voucherCode
  },
  [data[data.length - 1].serviceType]: {
    count: data[data.length - 1].count,
    voucherCode: data[data.length - 1].voucherCode
  }
});
```

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand this

Comment: Basically we group the array using reduce and get data by each serviceType and count and then we order them and get first and last element of the ordered array and make an object

Comment: I'll comment out the description then easy for you

Comment: Okay, how can i take this max and min and add them their vaucherCode ?
I have my old code to show you

Comment: the sortedArray[o] would have min and sortedArray[sortedArray.length-1] will have max

Comment: So the vauchercode is same for all items of the same servicetype ?

Comment: No, every service have a different voucherCode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223580/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-osher-revach).

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr=[
     {
        "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
        "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
        "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
        "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
        "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
      },
     {
        "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
        "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
        "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
        "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript2",
        "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
      },

]

const mapServiceTypes={
"Learn JavaScript":0
}
countserviceType=0

arr.map((el)=>{
  if(el["serviceType"]){
    countserviceType++
  const value=mapServiceTypes[el.serviceType]||0
  mapServiceTypes[el.serviceType]=value+1
  }
})

console.log(map)
console.log(countserviceType)
```

Comment: I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

You can group them into separate arrays based on their service types. Then you can get the length afterwards to get the count.

```
let Data = [
    {
        "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
        "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
        "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
        "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
        "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
    },
    {
        "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
        "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
        "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
        "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
        "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
    }
];

const sortedByServiceType = Data.reduce((acc, element)=>{
    acc[element.serviceType] || (acc[element.serviceType] = []);
    acc[element.serviceType].push(element);
    return acc;
},{});
```

The sortedByServiceType object would look like

```
{
    "Learn JavaScript" : [
        {
            "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
            "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
            "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
            "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
            "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
        },
        {
            "appointmentId": "fyeBbOtHkc1VIX9nZwqw",
            "businessId": "5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2",
            "serviceId": "RIgpGFxnSncs3RzSjQTs",
            "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
            "voucherCode": "tzDah8Yu",
        }
    ]
}
```

You can get the count by getting the length

```
count = sortedByServiceType["Learn JavaScript"].length + 1;
```

Comment: Hey thats seems very good, but in this case count = sortedByServiceType["Learn JavaScript"].length + 1; how can i make it more general? because if i switch to another user who dont have "javascript" as a service, this wont work

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Does this answer your question?
let serviceType = "Learn JavaScript";
count = sortedByServiceType[serviceType].length + 1;

Comment: you can obtain every kind of serviceType the user has by using Object.keys(sortedByServiceType)